# android drawable selection custom

Tags: android, android-drawable

To better explain: For example i have two languages available. Thats why i will have image for English and image for Russian. Both of them i reference in one drawable xml file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_eng"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_ru"></item>

</selector>
```

What type of drawable xml files i should use ?
How can i set and detect state and switch image ? Basicly it works like `android:state_`

Comment: I think you misunderstand the selector usage. A selector is used to show differences between states like focused, active, pressed etc. It is not something like a select/dropdown you might know from HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to use one image when the phone is in English, and the other when the phone is in Russian. You should use the language modifiers on the drawable folder, not in the drawable name.

So, you would have a folder named drawable-en, which would contain your image for English (drawable-en/image.png, for example). Then, have another folder named drawable-ru which contains your Russian version of the image, but it must have the same name (drawable-ru/image.png).

Then, in your layout XML (or wherever you're referencing the drawable) just reference @drawable/image ... Android will automatically choose the appropriate image.

Answer (score 1):

Please read how [Android resource Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) work.

You don't have to use selector for that , or force anything.

just put your image file in the following folders:

- res/drawable-en
- res/drawable-ru

and in your code you can use:

```
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

The app will select the suitable one based on the phone's language